# Google Places API Dropdown does not show up

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api, google-places, google-places-autocomplete

I am using Python Flask with Google Places API for Autocompleting Places. I want my website to autocomplete the place and then send it via `fetch` to the Flask server. For now, I just want to log the location to the console. However, when I implement the API using the Places API (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/autocomplete), the dropdown doesn't even show up. Here is a relevant snippet of my code:

```
<div id="locationField">
  <input
    id="autocomplete"
    placeholder="Enter your address"
    onfocus="geolocate()"
    type="text"
  />
</div>
<script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
  let placeSearch;
  let autocomplete;
  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
    // geographical location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
      { types: ["geocode"] }
    );
    // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
    // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
    autocomplete.setFields(["address_component"]);
    // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
    // address fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", getAddress);
  }
  
  function getAddress() {
    console.log(autocomplete.getPlace());
  }
  
  function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };
      const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy,
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thank You in advance!

EDIT:
I checked the Dev Tools and found 2 JS Errors: `submit:1 Uncaught (in promise) le` and `Uncaught ReferenceError: geolocate is not defined at HTMLInputElement.onfocus (submit:76)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the script that loads Google Maps JavaScript API:

```
<script defer
src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_API_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initMap">
```

Note that it has the following parameter `callback=initMap`. That means that once Google Maps JavaScript API is completely loaded it will call function with name `initMap()`.

This function doesn't exist in your code. You have another one with name `initAutocomplete()`, so you should use this function name in the callback parameter:

`callback=initAutocomplete`.

EDIT:

In addition you are not close properly  tags. The script that loads Maps JavaScript API must be closed with `</script>` tag and followed by `<script>` for the part of code that defines your functions.
Have a look at the code snippet that fixes your issues.

```html
<div id="locationField">
  <input
    id="autocomplete"
    placeholder="Enter your address"
    onfocus="geolocate()"
    type="text"
  />
</div>
<script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyDztlrk_3CnzGHo7CFvLFqE_2bUKEq1JEU&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete">
</script>
<script>
  let placeSearch;
  let autocomplete;
  function initAutocomplete() {
    // Create the autocomplete object, restricting the search predictions to
    // geographical location types.
    autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
      document.getElementById("autocomplete"),
      { types: ["geocode"] }
    );
    // Avoid paying for data that you don't need by restricting the set of
    // place fields that are returned to just the address components.
    autocomplete.setFields(["address_component"]);
    // When the user selects an address from the drop-down, populate the
    // address fields in the form.
    autocomplete.addListener("place_changed", getAddress);
  }
  
  function getAddress() {
    console.log(autocomplete.getPlace());
  }
  
  function geolocate() {
  if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition((position) => {
      const geolocation = {
        lat: position.coords.latitude,
        lng: position.coords.longitude,
      };
      const circle = new google.maps.Circle({
        center: geolocation,
        radius: position.coords.accuracy,
      });
      autocomplete.setBounds(circle.getBounds());
    });
  }
}
</script>
```

I hope this resolves your issue.

Comment: I changed the callback parameter but it still doesn't seem to work... `<script defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=MY_KEY&libraries=places&callback=initAutocomplete">`. I even tried clearing cache and using a different browser. I also checked the API Key by loading the src url on Google, and I got a long code file starting with `window.google = window.google`. So I believe the API KEY is correct and works. Any other possible fixes?

Comment: I edited the question with the 2 errors I found on DevTools, does that help?

Comment: I edited my answer and created a code snippet that fixes your code. Run the snippet to see it in action.

Comment: Thank You! I thought the Javascript Code should go inside the script defer that links to the API, instead of in another script. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Can you do two callbacks? I need one for map and one for the autocomplete but not sure how to approach it. Maybe two script tags with the same key?

Comment: The script tag isn't what matters, it's the function. You can put your code for both map and autocomplete within one function in one script tag, and use that as the callback.